# The program has exited with code 0 (0x0). C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I got this error. I'm using OpenCV and I'm tryng to detect more templates in a single image. Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    cv::Mat ref = cv::imread("image.jpg");
    for (int i = 0; i < numTemplates; i++){

        cv::Mat tpl = cv::imread(names[i]);
        if (ref.empty() || tpl.empty())
            return -1;

        cv::Mat gref, gtpl;

        cv::cvtColor(tpl, gtpl, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::cvtColor(ref, gref, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::Mat res(ref.rows - tpl.rows + 1, ref.cols - tpl.cols + 1, CV_32FC1);
        cv::matchTemplate(gref, gtpl, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
        cv::threshold(res, res, 0.8, 1., CV_THRESH_TOZERO);

        while (true)
        {
            double minval, maxval, threshold = 0.8;
            cv::Point minloc, maxloc;
            cv::minMaxLoc(res, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);

            if (maxval >= threshold)
            {
                cv::rectangle(
                            ref,
                            maxloc,
                            cv::Point(maxloc.x + tpl.cols, maxloc.y + tpl.rows),
                            CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2
                            );
                cv::floodFill(res, maxloc, cv::Scalar(0), 0, cv::Scalar(.1), cv::Scalar(1.));
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    cv::imshow("reference", ref);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For your future questions, please include your code in the question itself instead of using pastebin.

Comment: Exit code 0 is a success code. What is a problem?

Comment: where are `numTemplates` and `names` declared? This works for me as soon as those variables are declared: e.g. `int numTemplates = 2; vector<string> names{ "some_image", "some_other_image" };`

Comment: Oh god that's really a beginner's mistake, I guess it's becouse I don't code from a while. Thanks for help :)

Comment: I mean I declared them outside as global vars, but I messed up with strings so the names vector was empty.

Comment: Apparently I'm doing something else wrong. The window is open but doesn't load.

Comment: Nvm it just needed more time to process i think. Everything works fine now, thankz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit code is the value your `main` return (there are some exceptions such that it could be the value sent to the `exit` function). A return value of 0 is (normally) considered to be a signal of success.

You could as an exercise try to return something else and see that it will exit with another exit code (but some program's might take that as an error indications from your program, so change it back afterwards).